# CSS responsive floating Tooltips - impossible?

Tags: css, responsive-design, tooltip

I am trying to make tooltips in pure css and I would like them to be responsive, meaning they should float inside and where there is no space on left side they should show on the right side or top or bottom side for example.

I am trying something like this

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L0f8Lg5e/8/)

```css
span {
  position: relative;
}
div {
  margin: 150px 100px 50px 50px;
  border: 1px solid Black;
  height: 100px;
}
left,
right,
bottom,
top {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  max-width: 90px;
}
left {
  left: 0;
}
right {
  right: 0;
}
bottom {
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
top {
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<span>
<div>
    <top>
        TOP
    </top>
    
    <bottom>
        BOTTOM
    </bottom>
    
    <right>
        RIGHT
    </right>
    
    <left>
        LEFT
    </left>
</div>
</span>
```

But it really doesn't work.

The real problem is that I can't set fixed widths for the parent element because they have to adapt to any parent element.

I am wondering if is this still possible in pure CSS but looks like I must calculate everything in javascript...

Comment: Have you look at [jQuery UI tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#default) yet?

Comment: This is NOT my fiddle, I found it from a simple google search for pure css tooltips. There is actually a lot on this out there, did you look first? http://jsfiddle.net/greypants/zgCb7/

Comment: @Rohit416 i would love to avoid using js

Comment: @J.J i can't use fixed dimensions, if you put width:auto on the tooltip you see it will not work

Comment: If I understand you [this](http://jsfiddle.net/L0f8Lg5e/30/) can help you.

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand you are doing everything fine, but you just forget that you parent is an inline element (`<span>`) therefore you must set it as `display:inline-block/block` in order to work.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente)**

> HTML (Hypertext Markup Language) elements are usually "inline"
>   elements or "block-level" elements. An inline element occupies only
>   the space bounded by the tags that define the inline element.
>   Elements
>
> The following elements are "inline":
>
> ```
> b, big, i, small, tt
> abbr, acronym, cite, code, dfn, em, kbd, strong, samp, time, var
> a, bdo, br, img, map, object, q, script, span, sub, sup
> button, input, label, select, textarea
> ```

So with that in mind your fiddle will be something like this:

#### Snippet

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  display: block
}
div {
  margin: 150px 100px 50px 50px;
  border: 1px solid Black;
  height: 100px;
}
left,
right,
bottom,
top {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  max-width: 90px;
}
left {
  left: 0;
}
right {
  right: 0;
}
bottom {
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
top {
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<span>
<div>
    <top>
        TOP
    </top>
    
    <bottom>
        BOTTOM
    </bottom>
    
    <right>
        RIGHT
    </right>
    
    <left>
        LEFT
    </left>
</div>
</span>
```

---

**Note:** with the snippet above the `left/right` child will be out of the `div` parent (without changing `margin` to it), which I'm not sure that's what you want.

So another option (if you want to keep them inside the `div` parent) is to set the `div` with `position:relative`

---

So in your fiddle by just adding that we have this result:

#### Snippet:

```css
div {
  margin: 150px 100px 50px 50px;
  border: 1px solid Black;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative
}
left,
right,
bottom,
top {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  max-width: 90px;
}
left {
  left: 0;
}
right {
  right: 0;
}
bottom {
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
top {
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<span>
<div>
    <top>
        TOP
    </top>
    
    <bottom>
        BOTTOM
    </bottom>
    
    <right>
        RIGHT
    </right>
    
    <left>
        LEFT
    </left>
</div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a fully responsive tooltip or modal which utilizes no javascript. *(external link to Codepen)*](http://codepen.io/dcdev/full/JGgpMa/)  You can activate the popup by hovering or clicking.

If you hover, the popup will dismiss once it loses focus (this is the typical behavior experienced on desktop for a tooltip).

You can also click the logo which is what would be done to trigger the popup on a mobile device.  If you have activated the popup via click, the popup will remain open until you click the popup a second time to dismiss it.  (This is the type of behavior that you would experience on a mobile device with a tooltip or modal window)

This utilizes no javascript by leveraging the CSS pseudo attribute `:target` and `pointer-events`.  For the `:hover` and `:active` classes I have used the general sibling selector and the immediate sibling selector because there is a known bug in some browser when you combine the use of pseudo selectors paired with sibling selectors.

```css
.badge {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
.logo {
  background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhyADIAMQdAG1tbWlpadLS0tvb22RkZPv7+4yMjHZ2dqqqqsrKynx8fLOzs+jo6GBgYKOjo1xcXIODg7q6uu7u7pSUlJubm3FxcfLy8vb29uHh4cLCwv///3R0dHNzc////wAAAAAAACH5BAEAAB0ALAAAAADIAMgAAAX/YCeOZGmeaKqupua+cFxYzCAkWbQsSO/vkUxCMGBYCrEkjMVsOp/QqBSqjFkGiYjDAFFsAIQGgRAom89jMYCjgBgckcTAUl1O7/i8Xl/XFBgCCBMQYGNjAQBrGxwbixyMjZCNBxWJAYZjABATCAIMSHV7oqOkeX0MGQ6EBA8NiBUVko+Ljo+2s7SMkLawAAENDwSaDhkMfaXIycoiVQUDEQYHrGQAB9a1utm329zduNa+YQQHBgsDF1XL6utUSs4IEJdkFY259ZHa2vXetvizuPUqyAsAoROoJOwSKhxRhcGCVcLoHcBWi+I2R5H8VdSF7eKsAxwKaVpgTMnCk8mU/1jIYOBXgFj8KmrE6LEfzXz8+vES6MpABjoIUQrFo8ShggYNqoHMWJPjvo409+2aapNWLly3JgFAqoCkyaFgmygZ4ABAMHodser0eJOqxm4boUK1yYEVAAcDvobd2yIGBgpmA2wAmZXjLosbcVL9989f05wcQQZ4AIAChqB8+SYh+wuA45yJ1S5emy0j4sKouVUECSYAXsyZUSZhUDap47R0RV+kKFXf4beFr+4uTevA1rsl7cRWGOPCgsmKQmNkmrtxTG9MqesmThpnrsAL0ClfviyJAAUPAkyUVbrqTYtT79U0rU/mZ8a64TM6MFmBANjkkRIDAxOIwcFEV4UGmf9ha+FDH1zYKYbbYaRhA1IYEyTnQoACxhDBAQ9UsN5o+KnGWFrvlYgfigzCNVeDuBnXwAYRAMihFH4Z4Ip2KyqW2m0LWnWad9NNqJ+KNv1iwGXj3djOCxlsdWBbbun0VHv1VdWiVA6eBuSDPkpXCyVJZRCDk0+6cMEE6RGGJFb0fSafYe85aOJMcF5nnVP5JFbcZBOI9wKaTMQwAHrVxOdnW4hF1dR9CT6amomqsYilfMY9oEBeTRJaQgwZ/HJfhI/tWd2kW+bJokzB9QZhd6u5YmannnYQgwNkjPhmd6fWKaGR2/GZm1zD9fgiN/wR4MBBGtRKAgwSGBCim0eaxiP/hdfeRmWxjQnnqJXz8TYqhZQ8YIAEtN4IAwMgosUobvK5yqWLeWYF76IM8gjkitO5aNEDB2hYKwwCmDXihBXyViLCRPpppVVbvggcxL+Fi90BSf03KJoEX0KYcAsDpKBv9u45rnsIU2wqrKeS2uCBZGi8obpQlgFpyaguBl+k9r6bM6/2SPhwTAxTnOysM5MHQwZk2CMnhWz1Oxe8u0GsML/HAju1jySf+Ah/DSDd7HIwLEDZUi2itm2vvnIXn55YBntPVFZ7i2qR2RVn1gLpygZlm7y+XSmlc47c7eGN9uq1q1A/3Hba2/L3gNiaQZkU2j9SqiLDPYLbM0Dceq3o/4IkCt51scYRQDlYBOdKMpX9Zk66yr4ZXmHCkrAaHMuDv637gZfIPLbfLgxQBoKmnqxzXEF7XuqlxELG+c8/x2WdkGVwmjRzLzAAhpu7DmfnuymOv7jJu/P5+M2rPj+qtbdIA4DA3LsgAcZL2Q56vSZPvS9234ob3FQGu2F5SWJcA9EB0LUxdrygANKilrDK9xg8SW9zvZugaNgHNCSBKW2B8xyIDHCQhMDAAQ84kADDV6y1VYleydOZqvgFmpJZ6kQIvJ1NHuCAvoliacIo2vNEBxrrYY1i3gpgy9Sin/+dz4MV7AclVOdDU7wAA8eLmtxaRrtXWRBkr9vZ5+4kRv/NKVFz1zsRfwLApO11SAMXOArayoi+031rXKzSVpeyJjRgeedH0TtSlnSCMQUIKiUvYJML3Ua1PybMaUQbmcNC97I5FZGJtbNe0OSygQdMoIpRgEECziYk8aGPUbd7XKvqZbfpOVFIKYMcz5rXmyYywiwJAOUTrugL8DnPTrnDWePCZ7uneRGHbgthinRYy5e5B0b8AUAbRwEDHX1MUZIM4ZtAZiQCXtCRIVOfC/FER0oqaBEYM4AuWbC0BqBFZJU6FjYLOB/2OLNqsSsaGO8FRc/5CphMVFjY1qmC7nFAPVoiFeNeiEbfCXNx2YQV5xpZOxA2L5hc4qYt+MOB5Fj/0QUFOtlCt7awxLkvoh1s6FNQ5MrR7UujuwPmBhrwyQbiyAUCsI2cYsfQbWKUZ9Wx5asYWU/TedBwgQQnJFW2FZnd4QVxHAfXXrpPimoTmYOkE0VvWJ98XjCb07No/AhgSJs6oWwphBpAH0pEMKptdJmkl7YgNM7MpSyspBvabh7AN7MWyn5ZFBpWRzM3tRIQkhWzZ10xGdB4mdGGqCwsdRxLpyeukYHDE8sLUChBnkLvOstsaUqlt8xhXbVzee2aPGXRJcOAqId+LagLMJCI1d6tsthK7c3sebqh2rG04VzZbdva05k0whfT1KwLHDAjlwlRS+OD1CZLGSHm/Q6G/8c0ajmXSBf9UaoBsHVjCq6ICNEJkqTdvagAgYrXtZ62SMWdaJCMyladITe2fXEBBRqAoLdkVIZ9fN+8suTZ1j4yuuq1468ax9I9cmdiQZ1peDOLAl565n+LdK98axjTuE1WavzzrtXQmJ2Apk86QfqCNPHLkM2mNXCCVKniuLtBGMnuoQDFo8gyDLu68hhGPPThCyTgi+yG04/7bM9CicaW/Ow2u26Vq46d16cWSggRmJWtBsxWYsSKycZMhhFPoydclip5vsZ66SVdRjgx1oKvLH6BBRQgVcKSkT2utA+x7AZPEANVWJdiLDy12LDKUvfMVXYczMoqXma4IAHuBP+tRj+MuyZb6kp37JNMraUwVBIxWDo8HA0fPMxnNiCXja5mc4co2OGuDL6vDtluF6noPvLPuXTlYpSJm85OdQ8Rk3xuahNaupJKtIvgvFMdf7PV6j6RxmqjiC88+ikXLIC/OEPsN7l1aRyjuNgGDHUA3TvYGtfXoXDrBsb6SuEHtsTPos7gl7OtzGV3k67WbbX5zonB4EpKk6TiDwlt+oIBAOCdVTvxC/eda7dIjZ4ybXKpBmxoVvpWtdONNpm5UQntPcsFCCCARXf2oE5rW6LdxZYf003OSjtl5fRO7Ovwnd5uVIAACGjgAyFAAOY1VLGtzmsOdTfmc3LVsz/XYFH/JxnFQO+OABA4pK2KB+y7NdK2JMYkrDNo7l0p74wWRBmrw+QorvbJFx6fugYiQAB6IM7Yg6Pben36Vk3vdH/PnTf1uFbRqSq8n/24eY02VM2eIxiA4KLd++ZOtwPq9bpFd/qd07dKMJ+XOEjMiTTUORv+VMuS+RI33ePF3qyCeaiUBrXETYt3IyYIj3xODX8ClgSmuT23lBecdCftcrmz+eI+B/wjQUs4G26xyoWly83FttwHDClM27Yq1+u7cSRP3tixvzjftRn2yRo6yDAoAM+THO7Lb5/45yaSaRvsew4X28zg9uZVp7wBqDOLyIJ5a1W7OFcusg2DnoZ52GV5/9F1Z3n0bNcyOyhmYBuAZa1zYdrRfnjjZLQmTqilciQyZVS2dR+UN8d3T6UmdpTFTWAgPAgAMDd2a+XWPv40Y9FmZazHQoE2YommOHyGdEY0droAIjmXSNgmV9o3TM/3e6TzMZmHaaNlHwolaRYzVRmWbvFDU3IWD9viMEt2cdfgYPzWZSBRCQcnEeAzUY5gDV4YC9YgfBE4EV54cINxV14kYuXzJxAAFAa3BuB2blUoRb5QXk5Ug5HwC2JABmmQFPRVKTcXiJcADDqFeRrFGkhxCIP4El+UaKWkZuJTC4nAKQnQdnEHYMSGTbygAKLoBUoFQGFwABSwABlABFmAAP8GUAHBIF3xsxVQBwdDkAALsAWBgTynYw1hUAGcsIpYkAGCMFMiJ0G553d4djI3h2psBxPdFIGAhoEqNgcScCgBgHy+MxhmAQHFUAcYEAFHkShAlSwUIADMAgMDsAAYIyLJxI0NoAARoCEDkgEQcDab01oRl0bbJ3jLJXITOGpPpngOCEcKkH+jpg3RtADpWAXO0UsTNFMQIDx1YAG4AoH2kjoOICh9UAAR8D1RFocYRXYWoSwuYACGx38R9oZWggglIQEHqYwbhQgUqQE1QAT0qAEC4Dpd0gAQgFn2YwMYAJQuEAHudBvJgmrQYgNFsBk350u80zuLBxUEoE7i13P/I3lmN7h9DTg/9nOQSaRuJQgDFrAA0eAL1WAAEcCRm5goG+WTHMkSxvESbRABQAFyq4YLYDB4LuCRZ4kIBwABC3CXGkBb6sFNh1VPfHQL9jdngnFvUol4jeGSX5l/rXQVcPYCAoAxwnBw4aApbbR2KfQnbCRnbJIUvZCIG9BGcYRQb9mDs3UU1OCFpyg8mxgLddMoD4dnjjMJAaAANPAF/7WMMgd4g0GZGgCT2VhOvfYCozQjzOMKwjN+j1ABDcCXMBkisLQIrqA9GdAApfGbB7GT4GknExEGSqkBFFBn1xV0AzZmnlEDifB3PyeL/YCcyplUt9QA2jMAYtBZYzgj/3d5m4xAEKBQABQAME8DIhAAVTdXCwPlAgzwC5ijkGTQRgMgDAlHfh52hY+QiTsJE/4WdMHUXfgJlqHTCA3AeX4AAfxldJ0UXhdACItAAHz5nbcXUFvRRvuFTr8pKGySPzgzQoU3KU5Da3cXeARwA4aXgjLkfdJxotk4cdbJlyFaOvXwEskRcl/QUX2pIzD1NQQwATiQABMwpRgDm8bjGeq3n9pzbbgpk2rlL8ZFADjQpKHVnnlXoF6ZnDGJemugPeu5HlfjCJmpAd9ZfyyKARpqgTOJFJfzoUu6WXlZd6+lmZzIj0CzccJUfzmAlYDWcqzVY1khpXUyJgQhHnF0Yf+h9ggNQAEFlwgm+WiZqoXTcYZfU5AaQJ28lQ2bBwrsYpms9Y67ljf2YKPPoS/dlkp/1JUviaLHNqYFFxIgyBFkJR73UwZIw1yY0whrmAjgGq6QQFagkK0wlg3xqSY8N0fGtHSa5hEEsAOPeVReRYQcYaonVqPhVTBsKia08BIMNGdkoJQF4ksiYg0Im7AIOwtVeUWVQEeRkIlfOg6btG3ZNkkBwANTKikjOnNZkQjPOqX0hHPOWVudep8AwEBRBQAyU7AYcXMIIAEMMLM0W7PYWH81pQF1KGD/0HEvgJLI+K4JNYT2EgA9sJwTp1tkJ6XFBbM1k6NGFU0BS2cAoD3/BduzNtoHBikYBACrOFVexecIPusHQPtv9FY4xWq0CICQ+sZ1LOislSkuEDOrGpAAbCgvLckBQHE/MeOD4OOPp3CQmxerdjhrKsYkM1pnIVis8YRpasu225hyjOh1poovjNC1mllbpVULVQmsAhEABIttAaEJFFC6pjsBE8ApyikNEOC5bFpEDTiHlXlNn7hs/2YVj5tpiVl3M9QITLt0DSuhxoF1HNAAsHmbAYA0cMoYYAOpSPEAD4BqqzsOqkpnEBaFOSsAYKtkSFVvNfG4iDdOSvikv2tguaoADARBkBuWy/cC1yYNsLmTduirCtuFqiu493WSqyZSh/qd6Odb/3q6DUb7HMI1Xx4ILyBbmV63AQKhlO9bebl6AHd5poo6ZAKxWrELFAwguNaJNP7bVdNRBsmxX7yTh0EFwQ2IAMl6fjlzdRiBr+JmvL/2ur3yALCJAZUQEhuAWQn6O2MIfn6qHhjjtcl5UAdjESCSsxZwwarXic16KhnLdiNmvqPqahlRvk9znBUgKCcYgZEgP5iFAOVZF3yJRYf5OWCjPfl5uH9TDeabLG0UASjoTJ5GWchHETbKNMUaVmGXJH2qnD2lC7DIlzOqnZUoI0jjPZYpnu5LGY7FjTYMLdAqw4nkyP21UWbBl45Ju6bkbJLLRKqziTUIhD4VF/hpFpiQyv+GcLDICUc6EhGw0AuuwJca4LLe2gDspgFiDMscIMuU3D1guQho90D7xcuyTLKUCmLQRz3kdrlDkKm2a1Ke+MUJrAEWQAEGgLravM0TQAEToABr0JwvEAHxkMoAYADCA6eoGgDaU7c8l8oBYABKubfQyrrMwhLyYAjxnJ5t2ULG+kzFqRs3RwQmy0+UaGmqUc1aCwMT0KSvyiwFgAFZsABxEJpb5sjbIA0HEJrOkAE8oIqhaZYSiqKOUJWEWZg4QNEJYNFM45Z5uDYidhGZyADCeSUzZtPJJzW6utAgJXIqtKJEWQcXwFwuPVYVUJNVIMdbHMT3ABIPAAEWXQcFcG3/rmmJ7TMxVdilRkDSSDesoLNrkNDKPF3LoMrASTGYHZkB6PFOdSMNXRvVBMMml5AXa2wVbo0AORl+AnCPLr0qwedhWGoLv3kEPCdLuHWBoBcQFWAAjN3Yjv3Yja0ACDcYYaAAFCAHDCABNGADqjAGg6GV+2EWwJgBA4ABM2sD0LAVIqIJjE0J+QAO/DUBpD2Umz0A8PALKuTJ7UqiuGF/GoCSEhOSlOfDDajKxo0JbvkPEzEQFdAGB7XKUPkrhSAMU2QIEJgsbUeq+dzcEIDd1G2vBqx0ahO8uCJ0Esd0UJGwg1G/642rcHIPqYkI86kr1TUdXijfsEDf18Bk3loJ/2WQCGZYVcNWQCTHGLP6jA6GaLwpaqf6aRfocHBFfeeDN2jrX1Dqc3fVSgnXodgBuAT6ZTndeFq3PxZXoipldk8UY6nyJaolea92qmWnXrjRjMUzn6FVPdd3ZEznyf2EbDXURNFIhFjtdzA35MJctS5gAVRoYvdES0pYrzPEsR1WfAAMXK1ygEkH1tcblQFZqrILUj9oLFhTUe25YPCngiZsgCcnUq0qt/5UqBMnLnKDMTmryy96ZG4Lc+ozf6qy4wBHTs2UgHqirDNopGmeYJXCgw+IQ68HU1bu46QF3lPJxzOneCdspGL+U4nVx810S5M6ZL5Ag70lgPmhelB+1f9Vvl7S2GG7PWsPtlIsbknvqVgvnLLht656Hkkol+N1FOSY/mnNHIIFfDV4+GyDVqL16tsnBJ3px0ybyndjhuM1ZumCZdAAPeoZSFwa/lk4ZgtADCXZ3YniG3kGmIzyBmD9t+2ADUBetXgpVXIsBz0MTEUD4nkT2O7Jw6lhBkjkp0eaFOgX5TNL9OTYxYKaHnoXMXt5XbYwJOtgHX8t+Csobl6G/tUrWa1GR2Xv/XaVTimDOyjj7NPYnmNl/oS4pU9XXlROrGcVRDVDl3kr2MJAA7hjU3BVh1V/VjErR+zuB+d7Ln17B+kPnvN6lSqfvO7DPDM7B6okrtu6p/JISuT/mW7e07hjLLRWXU1JpgPjF5GqOgdytapFsKRdTVdgAKj1D/e2bAPkJDrKzLYoPv9h+IDMmRWrImrsluhccodEX+Lkkkt/qzfrjkrq0MXoueM/EQ4uY1v3fRkP0S2ZUJ/2AXhvS9Xqs1TCPoznTd7sOx7xNMEfrWtW7ru/MTjtcEduX+eCrm5OT1ZJ0CbzPe9+qLFufjXDz4dXQTiDult5LE6fI5cthv+BRC9W05fQAUBtH6e/Zlbmvx7758rCx1afOuiELX/0ohcn/CDOFOZodRtp/RYpJeZ05D5axB++qwdZglY4Tz9GAcjnkG+dSllhSU5nc4R6ED7mh32Dwr1+/wYEAhu3kZw5luMpiiaLqqTsrqrdlnNsn/X68kwHguKiOXaSSuVRs3j4fq5UtGdtWXvY7E722ga5Ym01i5NOg0BaLLVlndFh1WPRXOI7TQkgsPa9cbmNUZGpGZoNzpVdYeUoAjlq/b3BsQXC0OC8HQQASNzlMTU5PICRQU5e/t18jTFinvJgGhbWxl2KgclepYVtrjQ4NGmILjVhAABURqLKbrLOsk050g4+7wZWC77OSHbxuspxayljhBonEVM0eMNJ2sJmUkrnJPaqAvKCT9vndpn5566GrTPZpggjlu7YEQye0uAidGPRtFe1yGFc1W0WvYNtNDGS9+sQij7nkP8sHHXEQbt8mVBQweaL1sua+3bJqSQloq+J86JYKoNTET42BxKiS6mnobKbNIs2i9kP6EihMDXh4ln0ZTObpwrFwjrxjbmkSomVOjDOJbSqEmvuBERwhyCwFhc92uiTZrR4XA48GGb27BEJAQKonYuKJOOO2Yh+sRQUHklW197OfLft48A4kFh0CgAKpVKGR56gCYcz4+Kt1BB9c90VRiq9dz2v/ibOM4c6CkvjaXJBAYEDEVc3onjX5lVua3TCJVTtGdzjFav4k81hSJHBwJdqENBgGfTlm6fSnhqvdtZJu8kB4+jS4ldxiAwdqNBAgPfvxCa0sw99910XlHryzRH/01NsDcgVPlIRGFArIKHQwAS/fZdHEwxwgFgrBhmUXk8UKkfdPPHJtZdfEcqW3WzvVPaIDtsFwMFoxWQoCjEZNFDBa+7Zt9dVJp4Hkz0rkpiXV6ssaN2J8P3YHBn6ZYBhjsE1YUBLI9o1JGPLOejig5ZR9eVHD+qCXTTKVXSUAVZeiaUGyXj41FcSgrnWPbdI01pFXWYE6J+8pdlTJwAw0F+c4GmQwAPLOMdmgteFOWKK/QiYT1tUFYSZiGsGlAMADyQA56KmaTCBKQb20leKgD6nw4xOiZUbfWTiWU+ksUz3wIWKngrecMWNNFkuqk0KIVCSTRYiMNcQmRo18clq/2S11a7AnRGkBasjMofFlh2lt/XU1XMkEogtXXUpJlBcg44pYWgncduthk1kQAAAiVl6Zmag0tOabjMttl6mxY6DopOWYpEfAVUCay+jpfxy57poSlkurSL2e5Geav55LFvaVBeYqRLfq0EBBjyg1rkklzdwsTeZpw+nMUMUUp9tQBgLYAYUEDHKjEpwlHF4apM0uz/llKtbHjvD5Y+QNStZpSUYfSOOQy9EDAMAEAsQXVar4WSnlTZWdiPwmHgIX2VS1sYQiJ7MdcoaDHDY0booWKjFSvv5j+CCFxQO0+MmJ/MJoQ1Qt913C0BAnYhHyRWoIYXbmJJWfYwbZv5g0/9CJwTwJ/TjKmmQ7+RmukbQwYjHlie5lIvMGt/bgQ1xvaentOMDHk4YJF7ncpyasvK5482TlntxfJkCRdTJA7pvzTtwxDxBnozN9zzb4W5oRfyJPDkv60DBUxiZUAeMaofp1suZegOr54yX69x7tHPiOmPXanKs88Z7I+hEA6gHvzjtSG/W2FPO1sOp/jXQaWTjWHu6QaiL0ehhjjtg75oggACEbW3jIgprxJWwAvFpgp87W6j6NIQAlG53HPSPBwHQAONcrmLkUpfiyrUu+8RuLKwr0SSOAoAYVm+GV/IaYHwSsk2NpUhzeZbllle441jsB+bD4Blalqj3KTEdxJD/AMsqAJY16SRz9aldepDTp2tB8EwKAp+RRmUArYXRXsTQgAMkxy/XvctI0+qYCPeEpMph0UEfq8LoHBA0MOaxawkkgLJ6+D9mcM5fS7tYAH0Im5D9YH7US2IkT7XHASjgUX902oR2BkQl9XCN6cOgFpf3CvY9QAGN22Apc7THC6gKMSiK4huz2BzQMcdwm6Qjxr4kvQlsC5K9LM0eM2DD7VwGImuMVRyT1CyhxE6K8NpBfsYzymmebo8Y0JIwD5cnzdwniNs4ZITCBaNaoiAADTAAvWSITontUQMR2IAq70HPrVyRVeTDHAmrGERcHiACAf0n/PbIAABRsjy0e52//wLmpZrtbyMEsNAXpUlRBO5RAKlsJ9SGxLZWnVEjP1QYn26XggNITwFI9OdJH/fLBQTgUXOMRJfU5wqSTetviDyhRjYwqgAsIJo87Wk6LeoAG5Kncw79UpPEViiCgeMRWHVASU1KVT2e0gH6BIAmaarITX6SRRKSp1rAFgAH7JKXZ62oOinw1A2sEkFLuxMVc6gKqdhCLWulQD+nutcZBhRvV30AAbDpSdggVSyUClFVNlMCAjwKr5F9bE8jy4AFKKAB48FhtORKEWbGU32aYJ9qFbCAspqVtNaLrAUyYAB9BsCMPJvO+fC5LE9VTAR9mJ8BMmCB0eqWtJHVwGkNAPk2fW1nbyZsG5egiNC6EkBfELjtdKNrXkYRowADQAAEQKgvH2VXLyCSVDhlUAH3BgACCBjAIyd63v+iVzgDWIABhtAAye1Lu4FsIbOmgVP2gZCyBzDAAgYgVb0CeK/TPQIDMuAACIDtAfMDQAXgeyRPQYMEJV4uZQEAAQdkALd7zDCN7xbQAjBAAAiYAIjD62NPkPiMc6yAMtzrYxdPAAECYEB/oVvjJ9uYtwNIQAQcYAAIKIADYDuw5A7j5S+H98DLUAAEDOCACCRgAM/dsGOhDGU277EAFmDAAASQgAxEYAELQACf+6znCGQgAQIYAAMs0GQ4uzkPIQAAOw==');
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto
}
#trigger a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.dialog {
  background: #fff;
  bottom: 100%;
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  left: -25px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
}
#trigger:hover ~ .dialog,
#trigger:hover + .dialog #trigger:active ~ .dialog,
#trigger:active + .dialog {
  opacity: 1;
}
.dialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.close.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="badge" style="margin-top:150px;">
  <div id="trigger" class="logo">
    <a href="#open1">&nbsp;</a>
  </div>
  <div id="open1" class="dialog">
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close box"></a>
    <h2>Tooltip</h2>

    <p>Click this tooltip to dismiss.</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's impossible, but i share some good features which helps you use pure css.

Get title content from attribute and methon calc(); in css3

```
div.main {
        margin:150px 100px 50px 50px;
        border: 1px solid Black;
        height:100px;
      position: relative;
    }
    div.main div {
        position: absolute;
        background:black;
        color:white;
        max-width:90px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: default;
    }
    .left {
        left:0;
    }
    .right {
        right:0;
    }
    .bottom {
        margin:0 auto;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
    }
    .top {
     margin:0 auto;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
    }
    div div.left:hover:after, div div.bottom:hover:after {
      right: auto;
    }
    div div:hover:after {
      content: attr(title);
      position: absolute;
      bottom: calc(100% + 8px);
      min-width: 100%!important;
      padding: 1px 6px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      color: #304957;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: #C5E1F0;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #86AEC4;
    }
    div div:hover:before {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
      border-color: #304957 transparent transparent transparent;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: -8px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -6px;
    }

<div class="main">
    <div class="top" title="WopTop WopTop WopTop  WopTop WopTop">
        TOP
    </div>

    <div class="bottom" title="ZafKopZafKopZafKop ZafKop ZafKopZafKop ZafKopZafKopZafKop">
        BOTTOM
    </div>

    <div class="right" title="Willy">
        RIGHT
    </div>

    <div  class="left" title="Garbuzov">
        LEFT
    </div>
</div>
```